# JS unexpected Char

Tags: javascript, unity3d

Имеется код. Он не мой и писал его не я. Вроде, по тому, что я знаю, он является правильным и ошибок в нем нету. Но Unity3D выдает ошибку:

> (1, 15) BCE0044 unexpected char ";".

Кто поможет разобрать  проблему? Данные код я уже немного поправил, но все равно не работает.

```
#pragma strict
@script ExecuteInEditMode;
function Start () {

}

var bool : boolean = false;
var ts1 : Transform[];
function Update () {
    if(bool){
        bool : false;
        var ts : new Array();
        for(var trans : Transform in transform){
            if(!trans.active){
                ts.Add(trans);
            }
        }
        ts1 = new Array(ts.Count);
        for(var i=0; i<ts.length; i++){
            ts1[i] = ts[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Уберите точку с запятой в предложения #pragma, раз просят.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow исправил код, как он должен быть и получаю таки ошибки http://prntscr.com/cyi2hh

Comment: Но если вы пишите, что он правильный. то откуда ошибки?:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow а вот честно, не знаю... можете перепроверить. Я обновил сам код в вопросе ))

Comment: Говорит, что данное предложение неверно  bool : false;. Что оно означает? Может быть имеется в виду bool = false;? То же самое со следующим после данного предложением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> по тому что я знаю, он является правильным и ошибок в нем нету

Наглая ложь)) Синтаксис нарушен и работал? Это слишком магично.

Ошибки:

1. `bool = false;` - т.к. вы уже объявили переменную выше, а тут надо присваивать значение.
2. `var ts : Array  = new Array();`, т.к. вы **объявляете** массив. Странно, что не заметили, ведь в начале скрипта у вас идут аж два объявления
3. вместо `if(!trans.active){` должно быть `if(!trans.gameObject.active){`, т.к. у `Transform` нет свойства `active`

Как это могло работать, как вы говорите, я не представляю. Видимо в параллельной вселенной))

Итог:

```
#pragma strict
@script ExecuteInEditMode;
function Start () {

}

var bool : boolean = false;
var ts1 : Transform[];
function Update () {
    if(bool){
        bool = false;
        var ts : Array  = new Array();
        for(var trans : Transform in transform){
            if(!trans.gameObject.active){
                ts.Add(trans);
            }
        }
        ts1 = new Array(ts.Count);
        for(var i=0; i<ts.length; i++){
            ts1[i] = ts[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: в параллельной вселенной, всегда все очень хорошо работает :D